# highcharts php array unset/reset keys after sorting

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-18
        [1] => 22 SSH
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-18
        [1] => 80 HTTP
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-18
        [1] => 3389 Remote Desktop
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-19
        [1] => 3389 Remote Desktop
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-07-19
        [1] => 3389 Remote Desktop
    )
)
```

and the following function to bring the data in the needed format/array for highcharts:

```
$result = array();
$result[0] = array();
$result[0][data] = array();
foreach ($stack_stats_timeline as $key => &$value) {
    if(!in_array($value[0], $result[0][data], true)) array_push($result[0][data], $value[0]);  
    $hash = $value[1];
    $result[$hash][name] = $value[1];
    $result[$hash][data][$value[0]] += 1;  
}
```

so far so good... hoever the problem is that when i do

```
$result = json_encode($result);
print_r($result);
```

I get

```
[{"data":["2015-07-01","2015-07-02","2015-07-03"]},{"name":"8080 Unknown","data":{"2015-07-01":4,"2015-07-02":8,"2015-07-03":5}},{"name":"8118 Unknown","data":{"2015-07-01":3}},{"name":"3389 Remote Desktop","data":{"2015-07-01":14,"2015-07-02":52,"2015-07-03":65}},{"name":"80 HTTP","data":{"2015-07-01":3,"2015-07-02":12,"2015-07-03":7}},{"name":"8228 Unknown","data":{"2015-07-01":3}}]
```

the problem is in data when the format is:

```
{"key":number,"key":number}
```

this should be only:

```
{number,number}
```

QUESTION: How can I remove the array keys after I sorted the occurences by date?

Comment: do you want to remove all the keys?

Comment: hope `array_values()` will help you!

Comment: I have tried the array_values before. The array_values function does remove all keys only not the ones I want to remove :D the date keys stay... any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something along the lines of:

```
$headings = $result[0]['data'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[1]); $i ++) {
    $data = $result[1][$i]['data'];
    $newdata = array();
    foreach($headings as $key)
        $newdata[] = isset($data[$key]) ? $data[$key] : 0;
    $result[1][$i]['data'] = $newdata;
}
```